# Prevent split of the keyboard and block it

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, ios5, uikeyboard

Can I use UIKeyboardWillChangeFrameNotification to prevent the user to change the keyboard layout? I've some buttons on it and I don't want the splited keyboard, because it creates some ui problems.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you have no control over the behavior of the system keyboard. Your only real option is to make your UI work properly with the split one. Keep in mind, though, that since the split keyboard can be moved, it doesn’t matter if it’s covering parts of your interface—if the user splits their keyboard, moving it out of the way of what they’re trying to interact with then becomes their problem.